# Why can't non terminal carbon in a carbon chain does not form ionic bond?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Why can't non terminal carbons can form like:
                 _---na+
Ch3-ch2-ch-ch3

Answer (score 3):

Nonterminal carbons actually can form ionic bonds or at least bonds with strong ionic character, the latter case being much more common with any sort of carbon.  With magnesium at the other end of the bond, for example, the isopropyl Grignard reagent $\ce{CH3CH(MgCl)CH3}$ is [commercially available](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/230111?lang=en&region=US).